# SwiftUI Image crashes when you add dark mode asset

Tags: swiftui

I've been using SwiftUI on this simple WidgetKit (iOS 14) successfully, until I added a dark mode asset (PDF) to the image:
[image]

If I choose, under "appearance" on the right, "Any, Dark", the widget crashes. I thought SwiftUI would handle this gracefully... Is there a "proper" way to take advantage of the image set's appearances, or do I have to do write the logic to choose between 2 image sets?

Comment: I am using this feature in my app not Widget and it works fine. So maybe the crash is for something else. I have Render As set as Default for my case but I doubt that would make a crash if chosen something else such as Original Image in your case. Try to use the same image for both Any and Dark to see if you still get the crash. And play with other combinations to see if the crash is indeed because of this.

Comment: for me, it's not using dark appearance icon.